# Can we use under before deception?

Tags: grammar, sentence, sentence-meaning

Can we say something like this?

> he was under the deception of a false idea he sold his belongings.

or

> he was under the deception of a false promise he sold his belongings.

Are these grammatically wrong or is it just gibberish conveying no meaning?

Comment: The fixed phrase is "under the impression".  By [contrast](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+the+impression%2Cunder+the+deception&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), "under the deception" is rare to non-existent

Answer (score 2):

I think fev's answer does an excellent job of covering the subtleties of *deception* and *delusion/impression.*

*"Deception"* involves "trickery", "swindling", and things of that sort. One can *use* deception to achieve a certain end. So, it doesn't make sense to say "One is under deception."

By contrast, if a person labours under a certain illusion owing to lack of foresight or knowledge or by being someone else's target of *deception*, one could say that that person is under a *(false) impression* or under the *delusion* of something.

The bottomline is *deception* involves some  crafty act, whereas *delusion* is more of a "passive state" of being.

Comment: It is not obvious how the first two sentences of the second paragraph entail the third one. How exactly does the meaning of *deception* entail that 'it doesn't make sense' to use *under* with it?

Comment: @jsw29 You're right the _cause- effect_ relationship isn't implied in the para. Need to edit it out. Later, maybe. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely say

> under the *delusion*

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delusion) defines *delusion* and gives an example with *under*:

> something that is falsely or delusively believed or propagated
>
> - ***under the delusion*** that they will finish on schedule

As for *deception*, it is rarely used with *under*,and  mostly without the article:

[image]

Looking at the some contexts, I see that *being under some deception* is common in religious texts and refers to *being deceived by something or someone* rather than *deceiving oneself*.

I would stick with ***under the delusion***. Of course, ***under the impression*** is a set phrase but has milder connotations.

HOWEVER
*to be under the delusion of something false* is tautological. Also, both your sentences do not make sense grammatically. I suggest beginning them with ***Being under*** or simply ***Under*** and adding a comma after *idea* and *promise* respectively. I am not very happy even with this result, but I have already crossed the line of proofreading, so I will stop here.

Comment: Is it fair to summarise this answer as 'Yes, we **can** use *under* with *deception*, **but** it is unusual to do so (and, by the way, there are problems with the OP's examples, that are unrelated to the choice of the preposition)'?

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, the structure is 'correct' grammatically but uncommon and reserved to contexts different from the OP. Basically I _**don't**_ recommend it in these two sentences.

Answer (score -1):

While the phrase "under the deception" is grammatically possible in the sense that it is not gibberish, it would not be used by a native speaker.

To me, English is a musical and subtle language and the harmony (or discord) of a phrase will often tell you whether something is correct or not. "Under the deception" sounds clumsy.

A collocation that native speakers would use would be 'deceived by a false promise, he sold his belongings.' (see [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/be-deceived-by-something-or-someone))

Comment: This is a good answer. *Under the deception* is understandable but not commonly heard. It could be used effectively in advertising, or in constructions where *under* is used repeatedly and the writer wants to draw attention to the deception, e.g. “He was undersized, underage, and under the complete deception of his cousin, who was underinformed to a degree that would only emerge at a much later point in the expedition.”